# Can we wget with file list and renaming destination files?

Tags: wget

I have this **wget** command:

```
sudo wget --user-agent='some-agent' --referer=http://some-referrer.html -N -r -nH --cut-dirs=x --timeout=xxx --directory-prefix=/directory/for/downloaded/files -i list-of-files-to-download.txt
```

**-N** will check if there is actually a newer file to download.

**-r** will turn the recursive retrieving on.

**-nH** will disable the generation of host-prefixed directories.

**--cut-dirs=X** will avoid the generation of the host's subdirectories.

**--timeout=xxx** will, well, timeout :)

**--directory-prefix** will store files in the desired directorty.

This works nice, no problem.

Now, to the **issue**:

Let's say my files-to-download.txt has these kind of files:

```
http://website/directory1/picture-same-name.jpg
http://website/directory2/picture-same-name.jpg
http://website/directory3/picture-same-name.jpg
etc...
```

You can see the problem: on the second download, wget will see we already have a picture-same-name.jpg, so it won't download the second or any of the following ones with the same name. I cannot mirror the directory structure because I need all the downloaded files to be in the same directory. I can't use the **-O** option because it clashes with **--N**, and I need that. I've tried to use **-nd**, but doesn't seem to work for me.

So, ideally, I need to be able to:

**a.-** wget from a list of url's the way I do now, keeping my parameters.

**b.-** get all files at the same directory and being able to rename each file.

Does anybody have any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 approaches -

1. Use the "-nc" or the "--no-clobber" option. From the man page -

> ```
>   -nc
>   --no-clobber
>       If a file is downloaded more than once in the same directory, >Wget's behavior depends on a few options, including -nc.  In certain >cases, the local file will be
>       clobbered, or overwritten, upon repeated download.  In other >cases it will be preserved.
>
>       When running Wget without -N, -nc, -r, or -p, downloading the >same file in the same directory will result in the original copy of file >being preserved and the second copy
>       being named file.1.  If that file is downloaded yet again, the >third copy will be named file.2, and so on.  (This is also the behavior >with -nd, even if -r or -p are in
>       effect.)  When -nc is specified, this behavior is suppressed, >and Wget will refuse to download newer copies of file.  Therefore, ""no->clobber"" is actually a misnomer in
>       this mode---it's not clobbering that's prevented (as the >numeric suffixes were already preventing clobbering), but rather the >multiple version saving that's prevented.
>
>       When running Wget with -r or -p, but without -N, -nd, or -nc, >re-downloading a file will result in the new copy simply overwriting the >old.  Adding -nc will prevent this
>       behavior, instead causing the original version to be preserved >and any newer copies on the server to be ignored.
>
>       When running Wget with -N, with or without -r or -p, the >decision as to whether or not to download a newer copy of a file depends >on the local and remote timestamp and
>       size of the file.  -nc may not be specified at the same time as >-N.
>
>       A combination with -O/--output-document is only accepted if the >given output file does not exist.
>
>       Note that when -nc is specified, files with the suffixes .html >or .htm will be loaded from the local disk and parsed as if they had been >retrieved from the Web.
> ```

As you can see from this man page entry, the behavior might be unpredictable/unexpected. You will need to see if it works for you.

2. Another approach would be to use a bash script. I am most comfortable using bash on *nix, so forgive the platform dependency. However the logic is sound, and with a bit of modifications, you can get it to work on other platforms/scripts as well.

Sample pseudocode bash script -

```
for i in `cat list-of-files-to-download.txt`;
do
wget <all your flags except the -i flag> $i -O /path/to/custom/directory/filename ;
done ;
```

You can modify the script to download each file to a temporary file, parse $i to get the filename from the URL, check if the file exists on the disk, and then take a decision to rename the temp file to the name that you want.

This offers much more control over your downloads.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without actually downloading the file?